# Html Agility Pack loop through Specific Row

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a table like this

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="data1">

    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I want to use Html Agility Pack to parse its specific row i.e i want to display row next to row which has id=data1

below is code I am trying ...

```
        //Selecting Document Node....

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(data);

        //Selecting Specific Node...

        var tableNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath should be like this: 
`//table/tbody/tr[@id='data1']/following-sibling::tr`